# c# shorthand binding of event listener during object instantiation?

Tags: c#, events, instantiation, shorthand

I find that I often like to create and add a new item to a list when populating lists in a loop:

```
foreach(var cat in ctx.InventoryCategories)
{
    pnl_catList.Controls.Add(new RadioButton()
    {
        Text = cat.CategoryName,
        Tag = cat,
        Checked = false,

        // how could I do this?
        Click += onClick(),
    })
}
```

But the only way I know now on how to add the event listener is the long way:

```
foreach(var cat in ctx.InventoryCategories)
{
    var newButton = new RadioButton()
    {
        Text = cat.CategoryName,
        Tag = cat,
        Checked = false,
    })

    newButton.Click += onClick();
    pnl_catList.Controls.Add(newButton);
}
```

Is this bad practice or is there a good short way to bind the events?

Comment: The latter is perfectly good practice. I can't find a sane way to add event handlers via an initializer.

Answer (score 2):

A field assignment and adding a member to an event are two different things. The C# language allows the use of = as an object initialization operator, but not += or -=, which are implemented as add and remove functions behind the scenes in the event class. It was a language choice - I believe it is based on the desire NOT to include complex functionality in the constructor to keep the initialization phase clean.

Getting around this restriction is possible, but no solution is easier to understand, and requires fewer lines of code than simply adding a listener after the object is initialized.

In short, there's no shorthand.